# *Flickering* red notification light?

Tags: motorola-droid-2, notification-led

I have a Droid 2 Global that I got a few days ago.  Today, its notification light started ***flickering*** red.  Not flashing or blinking, but flickering.  It will be dim and then get bright randomly, but never turn off.  The light is on when the phone is on, sleeping, and even when powered off - the only way to make it go away is to pull the battery.

[Here's a quick video I took](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQtGjgpuMLk); apologies for the poor quality.  When it looks like it has turned off, the light is really just very dim.

Any ideas what's wrong?  I'm having a real WTF moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it happens when the phone is off it's gotta be a bad hardware connection.  I'm guessing on of the leads just barely makes contact or something.  You may want to get a replacement.

Comment: I figured.  It has stopped for the moment, which leaves me even more confused.

Comment: Probably the temperature or something is affecting how much contact is made.  I assume it doesn't work reliably when it should actually be going on for notifications?

Comment: It is green when I get notifications, and seems fine.

Comment: Hmm okay.  Maybe there's multiple LEDs.  Or maybe there's a virus that makes it flicker red :P but yea probably the hardware issue.

Comment: Well, it seems to have resolved itself.  The red light has gone away and hasn't come back on.  I think I slept on it, and the heat did something strange.

Comment: I wonder: Given a bad circuit design, could it be that some nearby electromagnetic field causes the LED to flicker? I can remember stickers being sold with LEDs that would exactly do that...